# Preg_match page number

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have been trying a few expressions to do this but have not found one that works.

I am wanting to turn `/search/test/2` to (php) `/search/$query/$page` with regular expressions.

This is the only way I could think of doing this, `/^\/search\/(.*)(\/(\d*))?/` and it does not work, because I need the page number and the / before that to be optional.

Does anyone know a way to get an array with pre_match that only gets the information I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/^\/search\/(?<query>[^\/]*)(?:\/(?<page>\d*))?/
```

Optionally add `\/?` at the end to catch trailing slashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('@^/search/([^/]+)(?:/(\d+))?$@', $string, $matches)
```